# Reading images from google drive, process them and train a CNN model with them on the fly

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, keras-layer, pydrive

I am a bit new to Colab and Keras. I want to work on images that are of very large size (each image of 5 gb), available on google drive. Can I read those images directly from google drive, process them on the fly and train a model with those images (batch wise)? The resultant images will be stored on either my desktop or google drive. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Google drive can be loaded as a drive for the Colab, So when drive is mounted you can use regular python commands to read and write files. you can try something like this.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

This is just one way that I know, I believe there are other ways as well.

Here is a helpful [link](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d) for starting with Colab.

For BatchProcessing look for [Keras fit_generator](https://keras.io/models/sequential/).